# How to make a section header with an non-rectangular shape without ugly underflow?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I made an custom UITableView. Then I made a custom header for sections. It has round corners. But unfortunately, the rows of the section are visible in those round corners when the header floats over them.

I could just make a background color so the corners are not transparent. But that is not a solution since my whole table has a background image and the section header can move.

Is there any way to get the clipping region for the rows a little bit more downwards? I mean: They should not appear under that section header.

Comment: A screen shot would be helpful to understand exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the proper height set for the header view.